# New separation axiom?

Tags: gn.general-topology

I am looking for the name and notation of the following separation axiom , temporarily denoted by $T_i$ (where $i=\sqrt{-1}$ is the imaginary unit):

***Axiom $T_i$***: For any point $x$ of a topological space $X$ and any neighborhood $O_x$ of $x$ there is a closed subset $F$ in $X$ that contains $x$ and is contained in $O_x$.

It is easy to see that a topological space $X$ satisfies the axiom $T_i$ if and only if *each open set in $X$ is a union of closed sets*.

It is easy to check that the separation axiom $T_1$ is equivalent to $T_0+T_i$.

The connected doubleton is an example of a $T_0$-space which is not $T_i$.
Any anti-discrete space satisfies $T_i$ but not $T_0$. So, the axioms $T_0$
and $T_i$ are incomparable.

**Question**: Is the axiom $T_i$ known? If yes, where is it introduced and how is it denoted and called?

Comment: Something like $T_i$ is necessary for defining e.g. the pseudocharacter of a topological space. The pseudocharacter of a point $x$ in a topological space $X$ is the smallest cardinality $|\mathcal U|$ of a family $\mathcal U$ of neighborhoods of $x$ such that $\{x\}=\bigcap\mathcal U$. It is well-defined if and only if the open set $X\setminus\{x\}$ is a union of closed sets. Usually in this case topologists requre the axiom $T_1$ but we see that the weaker $T_i$ suffices.

Comment: Also if one like to consider networks of closed sets (s)he will need the axiom $T_i$.

Comment: To define the Borel chierarchy it is useful to have that every open set is a countable union of closed sets. This is a countable version of the axiom $T_i$.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space) calls this $R_0$ or symmetric.

Comment: You are right, this my axiom $T_i$ is equivalent to $R_0$ (which is not immediately evident). Thanks a lot.

Comment: მამუკა ჯიბლაძე, maybe write this your answer as the standard answer, which I will accept and will close the question as answered.

Comment: OK I did it. Although I actually was unable to answer your second question.

Comment: The De Morgan-ized form of this question was answered (by me) at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/10659/822

Comment: @Nate Nice! One question, if I may: why $\it Cromarty$?? :D

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: If I recall correctly, the OP of that question was using the user name "Cromarty" at the time.  He/she has since changed it to "yunone".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia article about ${\mathrm T}_1$ spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space) your ${\mathrm T}_i$-spaces are called $\it symmetric$ or ${\mathrm R}_0$-spaces. There are several equivalent conditions, my personal favorite being that point closures are antidiscrete.

Unfortunately I was not able to pin down the initial place where this axiom has been introduced or used. The article refers to two books, but I could not find anything about ${\mathrm R}_0$ there.

Comment: Both the nLab article https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/separation+axioms and the Wikipedia article were largely written by Toby Bartels, so I'll ask him if he can verify the references.

Comment: Ah: Toby wrote *this* Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom and there he gives Schechter as another reference. Maybe the $R_i$ axioms are there...

Comment: @Todd Thanks for the highly relevant reference! I'll still leave the one I had, for the sake of the list of equivalent conditions for ${\mathrm R}_0$. Looked in Schechter, could not find anything outside ${\mathrm T}_0$ there either.

Comment: It is not easy to google for these, what I stumbled upon is [a paper](https://www.sav.sk/journals/uploads/1030153703-Dr-So.pdf) where they refer to a 1978 book "General topology" by Császár and to "Quasi-Uniform Topological Spaces" by Murdeshwar & Naimpally (1966). Unfortunately I don't have access to either one of these.

Comment: There is also a [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1304184/characterize-r0-space-by-convergent-filters) post by user [el-tenedor](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/104897/el-tenedor) who seems to have written a textbook mentioning this notion, but I have no idea who this might be.

Comment: In [another paper](http://topology.auburn.edu/tp/reprints/v25/tp25202.pdf) the authors say the notion was introduced by Shanin in a paper in Doklady in 1943. Could not reach this one either.

Comment: I guess the term *symmetric* comes from the fact that these spaces are exactly those for which: $x \in \mathrm{cl}\{y\} \Leftrightarrow y \in \mathrm{cl}\{x\}$.

Comment: @RamirodelaVega Yes, one of the equivalent conditions is that the specialization preorder is an equivalence relation.